# Tagging (and uploading) a photo using RestFB

Tags: restfb

The following code **uploads a tagged photo to Facebook with RestFB**:

```
URL url = new URL("http://....");
facebookClient.publish(
    "me/photos", 
    Photo.class,
    BinaryAttachment.with("file.jpg", url.openStream()),
    Parameter.with("tags", "[{\"tag_uid\":\"myID\", \"x\" : 0.0, \"y\" : 0.0}]")
);
```

It works perfectly. However, I feel *there be dragons* in the penultimate line, and I'd like to replace `"[{\"tag_uid\":\"myID\", \"x\" : 0.0, \"y\" : 0.0}]"` with a variable `tags` defined as follows:

```
Photo.Tag tag = new Photo.Tag();
tag.setId("myID");
tag.setX(0.0);
tag.setY(0.0);

List<Photo.Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Photo.Tag>();
tags.add(tag);
```

But this doesn't work. Possibly because `android.util.Log.d("", tag.toString())` produces `Tag[... id=myID ...]`, 
rather than `Tag[... id=myID ...]`, i.e., **RestFB is using `id` rather than `tag_uid` as seems to be required**. Is this a RestFB bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Photo.Tag` type is used for getting information from Facebook not sending it to Facebook. You should create your own type like this:

```
 public class MyPhotoTag {
      @Facebook("tag_uid")
      private String tagUid;

      @Facebook
      private Double x;

      @Facebook
      private Double y;

      // add getter and setter here
 }
```

Your code should work with this new type.

It's not a RestFB bug, but should be made clear in the RestFB documentation.

Comment: I agree that *"`Photo.Tag` type is used for getting information from Facebook,"* but this need not mean that `Photo.Tag` is not for sending information to Facebook. Since, data received, should be the same as data sent. In particular, when I get a tag from Facebook, I expect it to be of type `MyPhotoTag`, not `Photo.Tag`. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: The Json received from Facebook looks different to the Json you have to send to Facebook. So they are not the same objects, they are only very similar. The object itself cannot know if `id` or `tag_uid` is used, we should provide some utilities but atm this is the easiest way to solve the current situation.